# Prove that an inequality holds

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, markov-chains

$\xi_1, \xi_2,...$ is an ergodic Markov chain with $\pi$ stationary distribution. Prove that there exists $C>0$ such that $\forall a,b,n$ $$|P(\xi_n = a\mid\xi_0 = b)- \pi| \leq C\lambda^n$$ where $\lambda\in (0, 1)$ is from the ergodic theorem.
I know Markov property, ergodic theorem, i was trying to estimate $P(\xi_n = a|\xi_0 = b)$ using summations of $P(\xi_0, \xi_1,...)$ but nothing works. Any hits? Thank you.

Comment: This is likely supposed to be done via coupling.  One way to do it is in the form of exercise 9 suggested by Doyle, in section 11.4 (page 452) of the free book by Grinstead and Snell https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf.  It is like your exercise but with more details supplied.  Set $\beta:=\pi$ to get the result.  Alternatively in the special case of a reversible chain, I proved something that implies this, explicitly using the SLEM, here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553007/crude-upper-bound-for-tv-distance-to-stationarity-for-a-markov-chain/