# Show $\|A^t v\|_1 \leq g^t \|v\|_1$ for a matrix $A$ with positive elements and $g>0$ being the largest positve eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, matrix-calculus

Let $$A:= \begin{pmatrix} a&b_1&b_1&\cdots&b_1 \\ b_2&a&b_2&\cdots&b_2 \\ b_3&b_3&a&\cdots&b_3 \\ \vdots&\cdots&&&\vdots \\b_m&b_m&b_m&\cdots&a \end{pmatrix}$$ be a $m\times m$ matrix such that all elements are (strictly) positive and $a+b_1+\cdots+b_m<1$ with $b_1+b_2+\dots+b_m<a$. WLOG assume $0<b_1\leq b_2\leq\dots \leq b_m$.

By Perron-Frobenius theorem, there exists a (strictly) positive eigenvalue $g>0$ with algebraic multiplicity 1 and an associated positive eigenvector.

> I want to show that $$\|A^t v\|_1 \leq g^t \|v\|_1$$ for $t\in \mathbb N$ where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the 1-norm and $v:=(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m)$.

What I have tried:

I was able to prove this for the case of $m=2$ by finding all the eigenvalues and diagonalizing $A$ to express $A^t$ explicitly. 
Also, I found that the characteristic polynomial $\phi(x)$ of $A$ is $\phi(x)=f(a-x)$ where $$f(y):=y^m-\sum_{i>j}b_i b_j y^{m-2}+2\sum_{i>j>k}b_ib_jb_ky^{m-3}- \dots+(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)b_1\dots b_m .$$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed notation slightly and put the $b_i$'s in a vector $\mathbf b$.  If we let diagonal matrix $D := \text{diag}\big(\mathbf b\big)$, then

$A = D\mathbf {11}^T - D + aI$ 
and consider similar matrix $C$, where
$D^\frac{1}{2}CD^\frac{-1}{2}= A$ and in particular

$C = D^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf {11}^TD^\frac{1}{2} - D^\frac{1}{2}(I)D^\frac{1}{2} + aI = D^\frac{1}{2}\big(\mathbf {11}^T - I\big)D^\frac{1}{2} + aI$
which is real symmetric

*now for the main problem*
$\big \Vert A^k \mathbf b\big \Vert_1 $
$= \mathbf 1^T A^k  \mathbf b$
$= \mathbf 1^T \big(A^k\big) D \mathbf 1$
$= \mathbf 1^T \big(D^\frac{1}{2}C D^\frac{-1}{2}\big)^kD \mathbf 1 $
$= \mathbf 1^T \big(D^\frac{1}{2}C^k D^\frac{-1}{2}\big)D \mathbf 1 $
$= \mathbf 1^T D^\frac{1}{2}C^k D^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf 1 $
$= \text{trace}\Big( C^{k} D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\Big)$
$\leq \Big\Vert C^{k} D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}$
$\leq \Big\Vert C^{k}\Big \Vert_{S_\infty}\cdot \Big\Vert D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}$
$= g^k \cdot \text{trace}\Big(D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\Big)$
$= g^k \cdot \text{trace}\Big(\mathbf 1^TD\mathbf 1 \Big)$
$= g^k \cdot \text{trace}\Big(\mathbf 1^T\mathbf b  \Big)$
$= g^k \cdot \big \Vert \mathbf b \big \Vert_1$
as desired

The inequalities follow because
1.) $\big(C^{k} D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\big)$ is a rank one matrix, so the trace gives its sole non-zero eigenvalue (in fact its Perron root) which is bounded above by it maximal singular value -- given by the Schatten infinity norm (also known as the Operator 2 norm)

2.) the Schatten norms are submultiplicative (and in the case here of the Operator 2 norm, this is directly provable by Cauchy Schwarz)

3.) $\big(D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\big)$ is positive semidefinite and rank one, so its maximal singular value is given by its sole non-zero eigenvalue which is given by its trace

Comment: I have some questions. 1. Why does $C^{k} D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}$ have rank one? Is it because $D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}$ has rank one (which can be seen direct calculation) ?

Comment: 2. Does $D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}$ have a sole non-zero eigenvalue because it is rank one?

Comment: 3. Finally, what led you to the similar matrix $C$? Did you want it to be real-symmetric, which I don't see being used in the proof? Or did you want $\|D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2}\|_2= \|\mathbf b\|_1$?

Comment: If you spend the time to really work through the very general $\text{rank}\big(\mathbf A\mathbf B\big) \leq \text{rank}\big(\mathbf A\big)$ and the equivalence of row and column rank, you'll conclude you cannot gain rank from matrix multiplication.  This means $\text{rank} (C^{k} D^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf 1\mathbf 1^TD^\frac{1}{2})\leq \text{rank}(\mathbf 1\mathbf 1^T)=1$.  The eigenvalue 0 has geo multiplicity $m-1$ by rank nullity.  Compute the trace to get the only eigenvalue 'not spoken for'.  The reason I wanted $C$ was because the perron root becomes $\sigma_1$ since the matrix is symmetric

Comment: I see that "symmetric matrix has its spectral radius equal to its 2-norm" is essential in your proof. Is there a name for the procedure of finding such a symmetric matrix $C$?

Comment: I think in general the answer is no (e.g. in general aside from the Perron root, your eigenvalues are likely not all $\in \mathbb R$).  For special classes of problems there is still hope.  The way $D$ showed up structurally reminded me of time reversible markov chains, see e.g. here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/3524002#3524002  . Speaking of- your OP is tagged "markov-chains" though your matrix isn't stochastic so I could only guess that this had to do with a transient block of a chain

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: By the way if you really are interested in using similarity transforms to make the Perron root $\to \sigma_1$ for an irreducible nonnegative matrix, and not doing this with the SLEM (more common I think), then there *is* a technique you can use by applying two separate similarity transforms.  To simplify I assume WLOG that perron root $= 1$.  First take right eigenvector $\mathbf v$ and consider $D=\text{diag}(\mathbf v)$.  Then $P = D^{-1}AD$ is a stochastic matrix.  It has a positive left eigenvector $\mathbf \pi$.

Comment: Consider $\Sigma := \text{diag}\big(\mathbf \pi\big)^\frac{1}{2} = \text{diag}\big(\mathbf w\big)$.    The matrix $\Sigma P \Sigma^{-1} =  \big(\Sigma D^{-1}\big)A\big(\Sigma D^{-1}\big)^{-1}$ has $\mathbf w$ as a left and right eigenvector with eigenvalue 1-- combined with Perron theory this implies $\sigma_1=1=$ perron root.   I leave the proof of this equality as an exercise or for a new thread.