# signs of the eigenvalues of a Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

A Markov matrix is a square matrix with nonnegative entries whose row sums are all $1$. From its Wikipedia page, I learn that all the eigenvalues of a Markov matrix are bounded by $1$. But it seems that some of eigenvalues could be complex or negative.

1. Under what condition does a Markov matrix have all real eigenvalues?
2. Under what condition does a Markov matrix have all positive eigenvalues?
3. 2. Under what condition does a Markov matrix have all nonnegative eigenvalues?

Comment: (1.) Typically when the markov chain is reversible  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/  (2.) this is a strange question though trivially if you ignore zeros, this comes when looking at even powers of the matrices for reversible chains