# Expected number of steps to return to a state

Tags: markov-process, random-walk

> Consider a simple finite graph  such as this graph
>
> [image: graph]
>
> If we start at $A$, what is the expected number of steps to return to $A$?

I know that the answer is $4$, but I'm not too sure how get this. Can anyone help me?

I calculated the transition matrix to be :

$$
P=  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 &1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
with states A,B,C,D,E

and the adjency matrix:
$$
B=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1/3 & 1/3 &1/3 & 0 \\
    1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
with states A,B,C,D,E

What should i do next?

Comment: What have you tried? You are more likely to get answers to your question if you show that you have put in some effort first

Comment: i have produced the transition and adjency matrix, but I am not sure what to do after this

Comment: [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3568897/edit) your question and add those in - people will then be able to help you understand whether they are correct or not

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**. If $\ s_X\ $ is the expected number steps to return to $\ A\ $ starting from state $\ X\ $, then $\ s_A, s_B, s_C, s_D, s_E\ $ must satisfy the following equations:
\begin{align}
s_A&=1+\frac{1}{3}\left(s_B+s_C+s_D\right)\\
s_B&=1+\frac{1}{3}\left(s_C+s_E\right)\\
s_C&=1+\frac{1}{2}s_B\\
s_D&=1+\frac{1}{2}s_E\\
s_E&=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(s_B+s_D\right)\ .
\end{align}
The last four of these give you four linear equations for the four unknowns $\ s_B, s_C, s_D, s_E\ $:
$$
\pmatrix{1&-\frac{1}{3}& 0& -\frac{1}{3}\\
-\frac{1}{2}&1&0&0\\
0&0&1& -\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2}&0& -\frac{1}{2}&1}\pmatrix{s_B\\s_C\\s_D\\s_E}= \pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1}\ ,
$$
which you should be able to solve by Gaussian elimination.  You can then calculate the value of $\ s_A\ $ by substituting the values of $\ s_B, s_C, $ and $\ s_E\ $ back into the first equation.

**Note:**  The titles of the matrices you've given need to be swapped: the adjacency matrix is the one whose entries are all ones and zeroes, and the transition matrix is the one whose entries are zeroes, halves and thirds.

Answer (score 1):

node $A$ has degree 3 in an undirected, connected graph.  The total degree is $3+3+2+2+2 = 12$

Then $\pi_A = \frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{4}$  and a basic result in markov chains tells us that $\pi_A = \frac{1}{\bar{X}} =\frac{1}{4}\longrightarrow \bar{X}=4$, i.e. you have an expected return time of $4$. This is your answer.

**The below addresses the steady state probability calculations.** I take $\pi_A = \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ as a known result (it is e.g. implied by the elementary renewal theorem though you can also prove it with linear algebra when there are finitely many states.)

changing the labels since $P$ is typically reserved for the transition matrix

$B=  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 &1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$ and

$P=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1/3 & 1/3 &1/3 & 0 \\
    1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

and using diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag}\big(3,3,2,2,2\big)$, you can directly see

$B=B^T$ and $P=D^{-1}B$

It should be pretty intuitive that the steady state probability (or if you prefer, the time averaged probability) is proportional to the degree of a given node.  If you want to prove this, consider that the above equations imply $P$ is reversible, because

$P^T = \big(D^{-1}B\big)^T = BD^{-1}\longrightarrow D^{-1}P^TD = D^{-1}\big(BD^{-1}\big)D =D^{-1}B = P$

this is equivalent to the detailed balance equations being satisfied and also shows that $\pi_i \propto d_{i,i}$ where the normalization constant comes from summing all components in $D$, i.e. summing $3+3+2+2+2=12$, so $\pi_i =\frac{d_{i,i}}{12}$

for avoidance of doubt on the steady state distribution, consider

$\mathbf \pi^T  P =\mathbf \pi^T \Big(\big(\frac{1}{12} D\big)^{-1}P^T\big(\frac{1}{12}D\big)\Big)=\Big(\mathbf \pi^T\big(\frac{1}{12} D\big)^{-1}\Big)P^T\big(\frac{1}{12}D\big) = \mathbf 1^T P^T\big(\frac{1}{12} D\big) = \mathbf 1^T\big(\frac{1}{12} D\big)= \mathbf \pi^T$

this thread:
[If $P$ is the transition matrix of a reversible Markov chain, why are its eigenvalues real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/)

may be helpful.

An alternative route to this result: you can also directly verify that $d_{i,i}p_{i,j} = d_{j,j}p_{j,i}$ in your transition matrix