# Invariant of reversible Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain with state space $\mathbb{X}$ and stochastic matrix $P$. 
If $\{X_n\}$ is **irreducible** and $\mathbb{X}$ is **finite**, then it has a *unique* invariant.

My **question** is: can we proceed to finding the invariant $\pi$ using the conditions of detailed balance:

$$
\pi(x)p(x,y) = \pi(y)p(y,x), \quad \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{X}^2 \quad \quad (1)
$$

or are there any other assumptions that have to be made before?

I know

$$
\pi = \pi P, \, \sum_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi(x)=1
$$

is the standard way to go, but equations $(1)$ seem a lot easier to solve, so I'd like to know if it's proper to use them in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a positive recurrent chain with a single communicating class will always have an invariant distribution that satisfies the *global balance equations*.   It is of course a lot easier to calculate using the simpler *detailed balance equations* -- but such a chain will satisfy those **iff** it is time reversible.  This is in fact the standard definition of time reversibility.

Comment: I thought irreducible chains with finite state space were always time reversible. What conditions the stochastic matrix has to satisfy for such a chain to be time reversible?

Comment: Pick e.g. a 3x3 permutation matrix that has a single communicating class -- this isn't time reversible.  For probabilistic ways of looking at this, e.g. Kolmogorov criterion -- the standard reference is Kelly's book, see the first chapter here -- http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~frank/BOOKS/kelly_book.html .  For finite states, you can also look at this from a spectral standpoint -- arbitrary chains may have non-real eigenvalues, but time reversible ones don't -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/3524002