# When is a Markov matrix unitarily diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

My guess is that a Markov matrix (i.e., $M \in M_n([0,1])$ and rows of $M$ sum to $1$) is unitarily diagonalizable iff $M$ is doubly stochastic (i.e., columns of $M$ also sum to $1$).

By the spectral theorem, a matrix is unitarily diagonalizable iff it is normal, so that's what my proof attempt is based on:

$(\Rightarrow)$
Represent the Markov matrix row-sum property as $M1 = 1$, where $1$ is a vector of all $1$s.
If $M$ is normal, then $$MM^* = M^*M \,.$$
Pre- and post-multiplying by $1$, we get $$1^*MM^*1 = 1^*M^*M1 \,,$$
and simplifying yields $$(M^*1)^*(M^*1) = (M1)^*(M1) = 1^*1 \,.$$

**Question 1:** Does this imply $M^*1 = 1$ (and therefore $M$ is doubly stochastic)? I know this doesn't hold in general (e.g., if $M$ is a rotation matrix, then this is false), but is this true for Markov matrices?

$(\Leftarrow)$
Assume $M$ is doubly stochastic.
Then, $$(M^*1)^*(M^*1) = (M1)^*(M1)\,,$$
which simplifies to $$1^*MM^*1 = 1^*M^*M1 \,.$$
**Question 2:** Does this imply $MM^* = M^*M$? I'm unsure if i can "divide out" the $1$ vectors.

Comment: Your conjecture is incorrect. As a counterexample, the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\1/2 & 0 & 1/2}
$$
is doubly stochastic but not normal.

Comment: However, it is true that if $M$ is a normal Markov matrix, then it must be doubly stochastic. Your proof does not work in its current form, though.

Comment: a more standard, and natural line of questioning relates to reversible markov chains.  If OP's conjecture were true, this would have rather bizarre implications for Birkhoff- von Neumann

Comment: @user8 Interesting. Is there a known result about matrices of reversible Markov chains and their normality?

Comment: @BenGrossmann reversible chains are diagonally similar to a real symmetric matrix, where the diagonal matrix is the square-root of the stationary distribution.  Ref e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157008/if-p-is-the-transition-matrix-of-a-reversible-markov-chain-why-are-its-eigenv/ so not quite normal but 'close'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I note in my comment, it is not true that doubly stochastic matrices are necessarily normal. As a counterexample, the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\\1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\1/2 & 0 & 1/2}
$$
is doubly stochastic, but not normal.

It is true that normal Markov matrices are necessarily doubly stochastic. One proof is as follows. Suppose that $M$ is Markov and normal. As you have noted, we have $M1 = 1$. Note that because $M$ is normal, the matrix $M - I$ is also normal. Moreover, note that for all matrices $A$, we have $Ax = 0 \implies A^*Ax = 0$ and
$$
A^*Ax = 0 \implies x^*A^*Ax = 0 \implies \|Ax\|^2 = 0 \implies Ax = 0,
$$
which is to say that $\ker(A) = \ker(A^*A)$. With that,
$$
M1 = 1 \implies\\
(M - I)1 = 0 \implies \\
(M-I)^*(M-I)1 = 0 \implies\\
(M-I)(M-I)^*1 = 0 \implies\\
(M - I)^*1 = 0 \implies\\
M^*1 = 1.
$$
Thus, the columns of $M$ sum to $1$.

Comment: Awesome proof, thank you! Your counterexample makes me wonder if adding irreducibility means doubly stochastic implies normal.

Comment: @vivek You’re welcome! I thought that my counterexample **is** irreducible.

Comment: It is reducible, see definition 2 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices). Also, this transition matrix represents two non-interacting Markov chains, so also reducible from that point of view.

Comment: Nice example.  @vivek compute $(M+ M^2 +M^3)$ and see that it is a positive matrix hence $M$ is irreducible.

Comment: Ah you're right my bad

Comment: @user Thanks! With Birkhoff-von Neumann in mind, I looked at the simplest possible convex combination of non-commuting permutation matrices.