# Non-stochastic matrix verifying detailed balance equations. Is it diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, diagonalization

1. Let $P$ be a real square matrix. $P=[P_{ij}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
2. Let $\pi$ be a positive real vector. $\pi=[\pi_j]\in\mathbb{R}^n: \pi_j>0$.
3. Let $P$ satisfy the [detailed balance equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#Reversible_Markov_chains) with $\pi$. $\pi_i P_{ij}=\pi_j P_{ji}$.

**Q**: Is $P$ diagonalizable?

If $P$ is a stochastic matrix, than the answer is [yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3524002/544105).

However, to my understanding, the [linked proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3524002/544105) never uses the fact that $P$ is stochastic, or that $\pi$ is the only eigenvector of $P$ with unit eigenvalue.

They show that the detailed balance equations (3.) imply that $P$ is similar to the symmetric $\big(D^\frac{1}{2} PD^\frac{-1}{2}\big)$, with $D := diag(\mathbf \pi)$. So, as long as $\pi_j^{-\frac12}$ is well defined, the proof should hold. Did I miss something?

**Question:** Do conditions 1., 2., and 3. imply that $P$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: This question is motivated by some transition rate matrices, arising naturally in Physics, which satisfy the detailed balance equations.

Comment: Your argument looks fine. By the way, is $\pi$ a left or right eigenvector of $P$?

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for the comment. In my question $\pi$ is not necessarily an eigenvector of $P$. $\pi_i P_{ij}=\pi_j P_{ji}\Rightarrow \pi^TP=\big[\sum_k\pi_kP_{kj}\big]=\big[\pi_j\sum_kP_{jk}\big]$. Thus, $\pi$ is a left eigeinvector of $P$ iff $\sum_kP_{jk}=\lambda ~~\forall_j$. In particular, $\pi$ is the eigenvector with $\lambda=1$ if $P$ is a [right stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix); or $\pi$ is the eigenvector with $\lambda=0$ if $P$ is a [right transition rate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix).

Comment: However, if am I not missing anything, the proof holds for any $P$ and positive $\pi$ satisfying the detailed balance equations. Irrespective of whether $\pi$ is an eigenvector or not.